# How to calculate coordinates to move the mouse cursor programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, logic, mouse, move

I have the code below and know that it is used to move the mouse cursor to a specific point on the screen.

The thing I do not understand is why the X and Y coordinates must be multiplied by 65535 and divided by the size of the screen.

Does it have anything to do with the conversion from a float to an integer type?

```
public void MoveMouse(PointF p)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
    {
        var move = new INPUT64[1];
        move[0] = new INPUT64();
        move[0].mi.dx = (int)(p.X * 65535 / ScreenSize.Width);
        move[0].mi.dy = (int)(p.Y * 65535 / ScreenSize.Height);
        move[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        SendInput(1, move, Marshal.SizeOf(move[0]));
    }
    else
    {
        var move = new INPUT32[1];
        move[0] = new INPUT32();
        move[0].mi.dx = (int)(p.X * 65535 / ScreenSize.Width);
        move[0].mi.dy = (int)(p.Y * 65535 / ScreenSize.Height);
        move[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
        SendInput(1, move, Marshal.SizeOf(move[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is about magic numbers, not about code review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start, .NET essentially wraps the native Win API for mouse programming as an [answer to a related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379119/1810429) explains.

Win API expresses absolute (versus relative) mouse coordinates as normalized 16-bit values (i.e. between 0 and 65,535 since 2^16 = 65,536).  See Win API [`mouse_event` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Now .NET [`System.Drawing.PointF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pointf.x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s `X` and `Y` properties are of type `Single`.  Huh?  Well, one way to express a 16-bit value is with a real number between 0 and 1, which can then be multiplied by 65,535 (i.e. the maximum 16-bit value)...to arrive at the corresponding value between 0 and 65,535.  This is why you see `p.X * 65535` and `p.Y * 65535`.

To map the 16-bit absolute X and Y mouse coordinates to the screen at hand, they need to be scaled to it since it is not 65,536 x 65,536 pixels: dividing them by `ScreenSize.Width` and `ScreenSize.Height` respectively achieves this.

There you have it I think.

If you are interested in reading more about all this, Daniel Moth's blog has a [reference implementation for moving the mouse cursor](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/mouseevent.aspx) and related explanations that you might want to consider in relation to the code you're trying to understand.  Also, you might find [another related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14873963/1810429) and the answers to it informative.

Answer (score 1):

65535 is the value of unsigned 16-bit interger. The mouse messages like which gives you mouse position etc are of maximum of  16 bits.

It is the maximum size(pixels) of a control in winforms.

Comment: ...and divided because?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the value 65536 to normalize the x and y coordinates to a value from 0 to 65535